# How can I get an interface's bandwidth at any given second from the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, script, bandwidth, command-line-tool

I am doing a school project in which I want to get the bandwidth of a network interface at any given second, or some other small increment of time. I need this for a Perl script I am working on. Therefore it needs to be non-interactive and just prints results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of bytes sent and received by `eth0` since the interface was brought up can be read in `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes` and `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes` respectively. The number of packets can be read in `…/tx_packets` and `…/rx_packets`. If you have an older kernel that doesn't provide these files, the data is available in the output of `/sbin/ifconfig eth0`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be:

- execute **ifconfig `interface name`** once, capture its output
- extract the values from "RX bytes" and "TX bytes"
- wait for one second
- repeat the first two steps again
- compute the deltas

Comment: Good answer too! Gilles' solution just happens to work perfect in my case.